# Add a bidi marker character to the beginning/end of specific lines

Tags: unicode, awk, sed, right-to-left, bidi

I am trying to fix a problem with subtitle files containing right-to-left text. FYI, an srt file's format is like this:

```
subtitle line number
start and end times
one OR MORE lines of text
a blank line
```

For example:

```
1
00:00:28,000 --> 00:00:32,500
‫«بر اساس داستانی واقعی»‏


2
00:01:33,279 --> 00:01:38,279
‫«شکارچی روباه»‏
این متن تست است

3
...
```

The solutions I have found on stackoverflow don't work for my case because it's neither every line nor lines 3 then 7 then 11 so on an so forth. 
I want to prefix the first line after each line containing "-->"  (for example lines 3 and 7 in the above sample) with the unicode character "RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING (U+202B)".
Ideally, I also want to suffix each line preceding the blank lines separating a batch of subtitle lines (for example lines 3 and 8 in the above sample) with the unicode character "RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK (U+200F)".
Is there a way to do that in awk or sed for example? Thank you.
PS.: I have put a sample file containing right-to-left text at the following link:
[sample srt file containing right-to-left text](http://cl.ly/2Q1t3h1P1d24)

Comment: This is very easily done in Perl. You might consider using it. Limiting yourself to sed solutions is hamstringing yourself when working with modern text.

Answer (score 2):

I do, unfortunately, not speak, read or write Persian, so I have no way of determining whether the output I get makes any sense at all (beyond looking at it with a hex editor to see the marks are there). Therefore I'll dumbly go by the algorithm you describe. I hope this gives useful results.

Since the file is easily small enough to fit into memory, a simple approach with sed is

```
sed ':a $!{N;ba}; s/-->[^\n]*\n/&\xe2\x80\xab/g; s/\r\?\n\r\?\n/\xe2\x80\x8f&/g' sample_rtl.srt
```

This works as follows:

```
:a $!{N;ba}                       # read the whole file into the pattern space

s/-->[^\n]*\n/&\xe2\x80\xab/g     # append u202b (e2 80 ab in UTF-8) to all
                                  # matches of "-->[^\n]*\n", i.e., insert it
                                  # after the newline of every line that
                                  # contains "-->"

s/\r\?\n\r\?\n/\xe2\x80\x8f&/g    # Where there are two line breaks in direct
                                  # succession (\r\?\n to handle Windows line
                                  # breaks, which your sample file has),
                                  # prepend u200f (e2 80 8f in UTF-8) to them.
```

An equivalent Perl solution (since something in BSD sed appears to not like the above) is

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { undef $/; } s/(-->[^\n]*\n)/\1\xe2\x80\xab/g;s/(\r?\n\r?\n)/\xe2\x80\x8f\1/g' sample_rtl.srt
```

This does very nearly the same thing. Undefining `$/` means that perl considers everything one big "line" (this is often called "slurp mode"), and then we can apply the same regexes (in slightly different notation).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried the command on a Mac OS X Yosemite Terminal. The output file was OK and worked (i.e. it was not damaged in contrast to my own efforts). But, the end result was the same as the one I got from the original file; i.e. it was as if the chars were not inserted. So, I diffed the files and based on what I see the files seem to be identical. I am not sure why it's not inserting the chars. Maybe terminal is treating the lines containing Persian text the other way around; considering the beginning of the line to be on the far left end and not on the right, like it should.

Comment: Oh, it's Persian? Sorry for mixing it up with Arabic (I know neither, as you may have guessed). That you're on Mac OS X may be related to the problem; it comes with BSD sed, while I test things with GNU sed -- the latter is common on Linux and has a number of extensions over BSD sed. I'll translate it to awk; maybe we have more luck with it. Or Perl. There's Perl on Mac OS X, isn't there?

Comment: No problem. It's common mistake. :) Thanks again for the effort. In the mean time I will try it on my Ubuntu VM and Raspbian too to see what the outcomes are.

Comment: I put it up in Perl; turns out it's a bit of a hassle to do in awk because awk has no backrefs. It does exactly the same thing, but with Perl it should be portable. (fingers crossed)

Comment: Thanks again. I can confirm that the chars are there now. I tried the initial script on Raspbian and the Perl one on Mac. Diffing the files confirms that now. However, in both instances the output is still no different. I don't know why. My best guess is still the incorrect treatment of beginning/end of lines. You don't need to modify the scripts. You have already done more than enough. I am not sure if I should choose your solution as the answer or not though, given the result. If you think I should, please advise and I will do so.

Comment: BTW, here are 2 links of what I was after. This one shows the mistreatment of chars on an iDevice (iPad in this case) http://cl.ly/image/0p0i310A2e3w. And this one shows how I wanted the text to appear: http://cl.ly/image/1a2f132z2K1m . If you look at the placement of chars "-" and """ you should notice the difference. In the Persian sentence as you see in the second case, the sentence starts with - on both lines followed by " on the second line (reading from right to left of course). However the chars we insert are not respected or misplaced and therefore we get what you see in the first link

Comment: I see what you mean, and I think it might mean that the video player doesn't handle bidirectional Unicode in subtitles per spec. There appear to be many things that don't properly support it -- some programs I tried showed the original file the way you wanted, some can't be persuaded to do it all. For what it's worth, if I'm reading the spec correctly, you have to balance every embedded marker with a PDF (U+202C). You could achieve this by replacing `\xe2\x80\x8f` in the above code with `\xe2\x80\xac` (to pop at the end of every paragraph).

Comment: Thanks again. I tried that too but it was to no avail. :( It's become very odd for me now. When I insert the chars manually the iDevice respects them and displays the text OK. But when they are inserted by sed or perl it acts as if the chars are not there. That's why I filled in a bug report on Apple's website. Maybe they follow it up. But I doubt it given their history of being snail-slow.

Comment: I really would not use UTF-8 bytes. Specify the encoding and then just used the code point numbers or with charnames, named characters. Using -CSAD will help from the command line.